# FInding starting addresses in memory with unions/structs in C

Tags: c, memory, struct, byte, unions

**PROBLEM**

My classmate and I are having trouble counting the memory and finding the start address for the last problem (see below).  We are not sure how to count the bytes in the union to find the starting address of users[20].userinfo.donor.amount[1].
The answer, according to our professor, is 8009.  Is this correct?

```
Assume that a char = 1 byte, int = 4 bytes, double = 8 bytes, and pointers are 4 bytes.

struct address {
   char street[100];
   char city[20];
   char state[2];
   char zip[10];
};
struct date {
   int month;
   int day;
   int year;
};
struct user {
   char login[20];
   char fullname[100];
   char password[30];
   struct address physical_address;
   struct date birthday;
   int user_type;
   union {
      struct {
         double salary;
     char *clearance;
      } admin;
      struct {
         date donationdate[2];
         double amount[2];
      } donor;
      struct {
         double wage;
     date datehired;
      } worker;
   } userinfo;
};

struct users[200];

If the users begins at a memory address 1000, what are the starting addresses (in bytes) of each of the following:
a) users[10]
b) users[15].physical_address.street
c) users[20].birthday.year
d) users[20].userinfo.donor.amount[1]

Solutions:
a) 4380
b) 6220
c) 8050
d) 8009
```

Comment: The size of the union is the size of the largest element it contains (which is `donor`).  By my calculations, even assuming the data is packed with no padding, your professor has made a mistake.  Actually, it's just a typo - it should be `8090`.

Comment: @paddy: I agree, it must have been a typo. Verification on [ideone](http://ideone.com/OoE5js).

Comment: Thank you all very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confirmed @paddy and @jxh comments via a test program below.
**8090** is the correct answer.

```
struct user *users = (struct user *) 1000;
// used __attribute__((packed)) on each structure
int main() {
  printf("size %zu %zu %zu %zu\n", sizeof(char), sizeof(int), sizeof(double), sizeof(void *));
  printf("%zu\n", (size_t)&users[10]                         );
  printf("%zu\n", (size_t)&users[15].physical_address.street );
  printf("%zu\n", (size_t)&users[20].birthday.year           );
  printf("%zu\n", (size_t)&users[20].userinfo.donor.amount[1]);
  return 0;
}
//size 1 4 8 4
//4380
//6220
//8050
//8090
```

Comment: @jxh My apologies, did not see your link with a program solution.  I'll delete mine should you like to post an answer.

Comment: Thank you all very much!